# Jetbrains Fleet how to attach debugger

Tags: java, quarkus, jetbrains-fleet

Hello as some of you already saw the new Fleet IDE from JetBrains has been released and I was curious to try it and learn more. I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question but I can't find how to debug a quarkus application without the main function. Fleet provides you with the maven commands and it runs quarkus on dev mode correctly but the debugger does not work. I have searched on how to attach a debugger on port 5005 but I don't seem to find anything that solved my problem. If anyone knows how to attach the debugger on port 5005 in Fleet let me know.

Comment: Quarkus automatically enables debugging in dev-mode but only for `localhost`. Can you try running `mvn quarkus:dev -DdebugHost=*`?

Comment: Hello, see my answer. And please, could you remove fleet tag on your question ? It doesn't refer to Jetbrains's IDE Fleet. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we have 2 ways we can try to achieve this.

You can either launch your run configuration as "Run and Debug", or attach manually debugger.

#### First method Run and Debug

Go to your Action panel, then type "run & debug"

[image: Action Panel]

Once open, you just have to select your usual run config

[image: Run Debug Panel]

### Second method manual Attach

Go to your Action panel, then search for "attach to process"

[image]

It'll open panel where you can manually type, or select from the list, the one you need to debug

Hope this helps !

Comment: Can you actually add this on the configuration so that when you press run and the maven command autoruns the quarkus application on dev mode the debugger also attaches?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found anything that indicate we can do this at the moment. It may be added in next releases.

Comment: Can you reload classes in attach mode of debugger?